# XCode 4.2: Tracking Down Deallocated NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I am trying to track down where an NSString is getting deallocated.  I have enabled GuardMalloc, NSZombie, and Log Malloc Stack for my application (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7708015/620197)).  When I run `info malloc-history 0x29d39fe0` in the console, I get the following error:

```
warning: MallocStackLoggingNoCompact not set in target's environment so the malloc history will not be available.
```

This is leading me to believe the error is with one of my library projects.  How could I enable the above for library projects?

Comment: Can you run in the profiler and look for zombies (ctrl-I, then select zombies)? Might be simpler than doing it by hand. I assume the result is the same.

Comment: @AdamShiemke  That was simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Adam for the lead (in the comments above).  I was able to use instruments to track down where the extra release was occurring (which happened on an autoreleased object).

I followed the instructions [here](http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie/).  Making sure the extended view was open, I was able to determine the exact line of code that had the offending release call.