# Phonebook iOS app using sqlite

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sqlite, sigabrt

I'm almost done with this project. I have created a small application of a phone book using SQLite. I'm facing a thread error after the successful build. In gist i'll tell you what i'm upto in this project. I have created a simple phonebook in which you can add Name, number and address of the person. There are two buttons to save and find the contacts. All the status are print in label. I have included and imported libsqlite3.dylib into the project. Once the build was done. I got a thread error in the main class stating libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception.

Any help? I'm almost done with this project.

my viewcontroller.h looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <sqlite3.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *address;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *phone;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *status;
- (IBAction)saveData:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)findContact:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *databasePath;
@property (nonatomic) sqlite3 *contactDB;
@end
```

and my viewcontroller.m looks like this:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = dirPaths[0];

    // Build the path to the database file
    _databasePath = [[NSString alloc]
                 initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                  @"contacts.db"]];

    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: _databasePath ] == NO)
    {
        const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            char *errMsg;
            const char *sql_stmt =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, PHONE TEXT)";

            if (sqlite3_exec(_contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                _status.text = @"Failed to create table";
            }
            sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
        }

        else

        {
            _status.text = @"Failed to open/create database";
        }
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)saveData:(id)sender
{
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                           @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS (name, address, phone) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",
                           self.name.text, self.address.text, self.phone.text];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB, insert_stmt,
                       -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            self.status.text = @"Contact added";
            self.name.text = @"";
            self.address.text = @"";
            self.phone.text = @"";
        }

        else

        {
            self.status.text = @"Failed to add contact";
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
    }
}

- (IBAction)findContact:(id)sender
{
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                          @"SELECT address, phone FROM contacts WHERE name=\"%@\"",
                          _name.text];

        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_contactDB,
                           query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSString *addressField = [[NSString alloc]
                                      initWithUTF8String:
                                      (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(
                                                                         statement, 0)];
                _address.text = addressField;
                NSString *phoneField = [[NSString alloc]
                                    initWithUTF8String:(const char *)
                                    sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
                _phone.text = phoneField;
                _status.text = @"Match found";
            }
            else
            {
                _status.text = @"Match not found";
                _address.text = @"";
                _phone.text = @"";
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        sqlite3_close(_contactDB);
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289014/null-libcabi-dylib-terminate-called-throwing-an-exception

Comment: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/475 take a look

Answer (score 0):

in your imports statement in ".h" file, have this instead:

```
#import "/usr/include/sqlite3.h"
```

You must specify the complete path for sqlite3 header file.