# libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception - 0 stack trace iOS7 / iOS 8

Tags: exception, ios7, crash, ios8, libc++

Randomly (that's why I ask the question), my application crashes when want to display data into textView.
The only error message I've got in my debug console is :

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception
```

I Googled but can't get a clue to find how correct this and how this happens.

Comment: I am getting similar error, and if I look at the stack trace, it looks like iOS is trying to NSLog a NSAutoLayoutContraint and it's causing the crash because this particular one doesn't have a description method implemented.

Comment: I don't use Autolayout. I use Autoresizing mask mechanism.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Clean the project.
Check each constraints and remove the corrupted one.
Clean project again, it should works.

Comment: Gonna try and I comme back.

Comment: Maybe this answers the user's question in his specific case, but it sure is not a solution to the given problem.

Answer (score 25):

I got the same error and a "clean" didn't resolve it.

It was caused by my internet testing flow, I check to see if WiFi is connected but not if that WiFi has an active internet connection that can resolve a supplied URL. It performs a dataWithContentsOfURL: that will ultimately fail. A similar thread made this suggestion to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289014/null-libcabi-dylib-terminate-called-throwing-an-exception) here by user Keith that helped me identify the problem -- which was to add breakpoints to C++ exceptions.

To enable -- click your breakpoints view and the very bottom click the '+' to add a breakpoint. Set it up as follows and the stack trance will be more meaningful. 
[image: Enable C++ Breakpoints]

Comment: This helped me a lot finding the issue, since there is no backtrace for C++ code caused crashes, and the breakpoint is the only way to stop executing the code and see when the crash occures. I think this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 10):

This can be caused by an outlet that is no longer existing (might have been renamed or removed).

Here is a tip on how to check outlets:
Select the container view of the suspected outlet, pay attention to "!" marks in the connections inspector.

[image: check constraints]

Answer (score 0):

I got this question ,because I set `[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"_defaultAgType" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];`, but I did not remove it in `dealloc`. I solved this by `[self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"_defaultAgType"];`  in dealloc function.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason why it could happen is when you have a UI element declared but never added to the screen but still you try to do changes on them.

In my case I had a `UIBarButtonItem` declared in the code but I never added it to View. When I try to remove it without adding it, I had this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you renamed/moved your view controller class, make sure you've checked `Inherit Module From Target` on Identity inspector for your scene on the storyboard

[image: Inherit Module From Target]