# libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception

Tags: ios

> Objective: {objective 0x7fb7a49de030: <750:216, 250:2804> +
>   <750:-9.93411e-08>*0x7fb7a4d254b0.negError{id: 1392} +
>   <750:-9.93411e-08>*UIButton:0x7fb7a4b87750.Width{id: 1233}}
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception

when i push or present a ViewController it crashed,this is the crash message,how to resolve it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [libc++abi.dylib: terminate\_handler unexpectedly threw an exception - 0 stack trace iOS7 / iOS 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932033/libcabi-dylib-terminate-handler-unexpectedly-threw-an-exception-0-stack-tra)

Answer (score 1):

Remove it libc++abi.dylib from build settings and try to libc++abi.tbd and check still issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to a disconnected outlet or a corrupt constraint. Try cleaning the project and building again. Check your outlets.

See answers on this SO thread for reference: [libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception - 0 stack trace iOS7 / iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932033/libcabi-dylib-terminate-handler-unexpectedly-threw-an-exception-0-stack-tra)