# Xcode7 not log crash report

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I update my xcode to xcode7 and I only update my project to swift2 . Then xcode begin not show crash report.it always just shows this message :

> "libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception".

I wonder how can I know the detail of the exception,or how to make my xcode log exception again?

Comment: Check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932033/libcabi-dylib-terminate-handler-unexpectedly-threw-an-exception-0-stack-tra

Comment: I have saw this question, it's about interface builder.But I always got this message when the question is not related to IB at all.

Answer (score 0):

Clean the project.Check each constraints and remove the corrupted one. or
Press
CMD+Shift+alt+k