# Can I catch an exception thrown before main()?

Tags: c++, exception, terminate

I have some library (actually the tbb library compiled with a different compiler), throwing an exception before `main()` proper started. Is there a way to catch that?

```
int main() { std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl; }
```

gives

```
terminating with unexpected foreign exception
Abort (core dumped)
```

if I link against said library (which is not used in this example, but in other code it will be).

Comment: ...? How is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? probably relevant [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289014/null-libcabi-dylib-terminate-called-throwing-an-exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289014/null-libcabi-dylib-terminate-called-throwing-an-exception)

Comment: Which OS are you targetting?

Comment: First of all it's not possible to catch an exception before `main` is called, unless you run in a debugger. Second of all catching such an exception would be pretty much useless, since your program would most likely not be able to continue anyway. Lastly, are you sure it's a C++ exception being thrown, and not an OS or hardware exception? Those are different things using the same terminology.

Comment: Are you willing to replace the standard startup files? C++ injects quite a lot of stuff before main, but you don't have to use the compilers version if you don't want to

Comment: @VermillionAzure Global variable with a constructor that throws an exception.

Comment: Have you tried `catch throw` in gdb ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: `try catch` works within functions called before main. (it is just not possible to have a "global" `try cacth`).

Comment: _"(compiled with a different compiler)"_ Don't do this

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/using-stdterminate/), author proposes a specific use of `std::terminate` and `std::current_exception` to achieve a general `try...catch` and also a way to set handler for `std::terminate` before call of `main` (but you can't be sure registration of handler is done before any instantiation)

Comment: As mention by @LightnessRacesinOrbit using different compilers *may* be a reason. But it really depends on the "other" compiler. And the "current" compiler. None of which we know unfortunately.

Comment: Libraries with global statics with throwing constructors = evil

Comment: You can `throw` from anywhere in the program but `catch` must be right after `try`. You can't throw or catch in `global scope`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Can you explain why you are saying that catching exceptions before `main` is not possible? You can execute functions (e.g. constructors) before `main` and have a perfectly valid stack. Is there something magic about `main`?

Comment: If it's a shared library, you might be able to defer library load until after `main()` has started - either by not linking it and using explicit `dlopen()`, or by marking it as lazy-loaded in your linker flags.

Comment: @EmeraldWeapon Yes it's possible to have global variables, or namespace variables, whose initialization calls functions where one can catch exceptions. But if you don't actually call the functions which throws the exception, then no it's not possible to catch it. And `main` *is* special as it's the function where everything really starts to run (global variable initialization aside). Without a `main` function you don't have a C++ *program*, just a collection of classes and functions really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, it is not possible in standard C++ to catch an exception that is thrown during construction of a global variable (which is outside scope of any function).

I believe the closest possibility is to use a function-try-block for the body of the constructor of the static.

```
 class MyStatics
 {
      public:

          MyStatics();

      private:

          X x;    // construction may fail
          Y y;    // construction may fail
            // etc
 };

 static MyStatics all_my_statics;

 MyStatics::Mystatics() : x(), y()   // implement using a function try block
 try
 {
     if (some_condition) throw some_exception();   // construction may even fail here
 }
 catch (SomeException &)
 {
     // handler for SomeException
 }
```

If an exception is thrown during construction of `all_my_statics`, then any fully-constructed members of it will be destructed (i.e. `MyStatics` members do not exist within such a `catch` block).

Within the `catch` block there aren't many options, after reporting about the caught exceptions.   The main options will be;

- throw (or rethrow) an exception (since the construction of `MyStatics` has failed).   That exception will cause `std::terminate()` to be called.
- terminate the program in some other way deemed to be "cleaner".

It is not a good idea to swallow an exception thrown during construction of a static since the program (e.g. within `main()`) will have no indication that statics it relies on have not been properly constructed.

It is more usual to place the static object within a function

```
  X &the_x()
  try
  {
       static X thing;
       return thing; 
  }
  catch (Whatever &)
  {
       // handler
  }
```

Bear in mind that every call of `the_x()` will attempt to construct `thing` until one of them succeeds   (i.e. if an exception is thrown the first time, the second call will attempt to construct `thing`, etc).   However, if the first call of `the_x()` within the program can be identified and exceptions from it caught (i.e. wrap it in a `try`/`catch`) it is not necessary to catch exceptions from subsequent calls - since, if the first call doesn't throw, the construction of `thing` has succeeded, and it will not be constructed again.

Answer (score 2):

I found this interesting [source](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/using-stdterminate/). It bases his construction on `std::terminate` functionality

He proposes to use a sort of global `try...catch` (you can't continue anymore to run, but you can act depending of exception):

```
[[noreturn]] void onTerminate() noexcept
{
    if( auto exc = std::current_exception() ) { 
        // we have an exception
        try{
            rethrow_exception( exc ); // throw to recognize the type
        }
        catch( MyException const& exc ) {
            // additional action
        }
        catch( MyOtherException const& exc ) {
            // additional action
        }
        catch( std::exception const& exc ) {
            // additional action
        }
       catch( ... ) {
            // additional action
        }
    }

    std::_Exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

and to register this caller when an exception occurred, earliest possible:

```
const auto installed{ std::set_terminate(&handler) };

int main() {
    // run...
}
```

But you have to know that you can't be sure that `std::set_terminate` will be called before any instanciation.

Comment: Not quite a "global try...catch". More like a catch inside terminate (you can still never continue execution).