# App crashing due to event store changed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ekeventkit, ekeventstore

I searched SO but didnt find any accurate answer for this.

I am implementing Event Kit in my app.I am programatically implementing creation of events,
But I am not specifying any calendar there.Then I am using the `EKEventViewController` to Edit my events.I am using the **Kal library** as well to show the calendar.Every time I edit the second or 3rd so on event, or event delete the event, My app crashes, It is saying that event store is changed.I am not able to solve this issue.

Can anyone help me in this.

Here is the Crash Log..

```
terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM eventStoreChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1fc7f040
```

Thanks

Comment: [Check out this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703052/xcode-doesnt-show-the-line-that-causes-a-crash) and see if you can narrow down the line of code where this exception is thrown from.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Thanks for your comment,But I am already doing the same thing..Problem is that for the EKEventViewController you dont have further excess,so cant get the source why its exactly happening...There is something that I am missing may be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had found the answer myself...If someone faces the same situation..Then here you go..
You need to set the eventstorechanged delegate to nil. And your problem would be solved.

Cheers
Sanjay