# Xcode - show the line that threw the exception

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703052/xcode-doesnt-show-the-line-that-causes-a-crash) Q&A.

I have the exact problem:

*"Every time my app crashes Xcode highlights the UIApicationMain() call in the main() function as the line that caused the crash"*

I tried the selected solution: adding breakpoint - on catch - for all exceptions.

But still, Xcode highlights the UIApplicationMain() function.

I am using XCode 4.6

What could cause it?

Comment: What kind of memory management are you using? ARC?

Comment: It is most likely a memory management issue where somewhere you are doing something you shouldn't be doing, you could try using the static analyzer in order to find some of such issues.

Comment: Add an "All Exceptions" breakpoint on throw. Then you see where it happens. You may need to press "continue" ones or twice before the related message appears.

Comment: Is it the same reason `reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an exception breakpoint indeed, but instead of `on catch` select `on throw` obviously.

Comment: this, I would use "objc_exception_throw" as the symbol for the breakpoint