# Program crashing after adding subview from NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, nsmutablearray

Right now I have a `UIView` with two subviews on it. I am trying to add another subview to one of those views, from a custom-made `Card` class. The problem is that the subview is coming from an NSMutableArray, and it makes the program crash every time I try to add it to any views. I know the issue has something to do with the NSMutableArray, because there isn't any problem if I just try to add an instance of Card that is initialized right then and there. What's the problem?

Here's the code:

Initialization of the main view where this is happening:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        mainMenu = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        mainMenu.frame = CGRectMake(10, 944, 100, 50);
        [mainMenu setTitle:@"Main Menu" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [mainMenu addTarget:self action:@selector(goMainMenu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        reader = [[Reader alloc] init];
        deck = [reader getDeck];

        hand = [[Hand alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 1024/3, 768, 2048/3)];

        board = [[Board alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024/3)];
    }
    return self;
}
```

method where the card is supposed to be added:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Card* card = [deck objectAtIndex:0];

    [hand addSubview:card];
    [self.view addSubview:hand];
    [self.view addSubview:board];
    [self.view addSubview:mainMenu];
}
```

and here is where the `getDeck` method is, in the `Reader` class:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getDeck {

    NSMutableArray* deck = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:72];

    Card* card;

    NSMutableArray* strings = [[scanner string] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

    while ([strings count] > 0) {

        [strings removeObjectAtIndex:0];

        card = [Card cardWithExpressions:[strings subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 4)]];
        card.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 180, 252);

        [card setCoefficient:[self getCoefficientFromExpression:[card getPolynomial]]];

        [deck addObject:card];

        [strings removeObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];
    }

    return deck;
}
```

Comment: You're probably going to need to add more information about how your program is crashing. What error message do you get? Where do you get it?

Comment: No error message. I'm using Xcode 4.2, which, as far as I know, doesn't give an error message. At least, it doesn't appear in the same place that it does in Xcode 3...Also, the error happens in the `main` method

Comment: it must show something in console area

Comment: Side note - if you are planning to write an app for the App Store, you need Xcode 4.5 or later.

Comment: @RaysonK Try following these instructions if you're seeing a crash which appears to be in main: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703052/xcode-doesnt-show-the-line-that-causes-a-crash

Comment: @JesseRusak I'll give that a try and see if that helps. Also, I edited the part where the `card` object is initialized to reflect how the code looks with the exception gets thrown

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It turns out that the initializer that I was using for `card`, which was `cardWithExpressions:`, didn't have the `[super initWithFrame:]` in it. Put that in there and now it's all working.