# Show exact line causing exception in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I have enabled exception breakpoints in xcode but whenever I encounter an exception it never takes me to the line that caused the exception to be thrown. All I get is this:

```
@autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])); thread 1: SIGABRT
    }
```

And the console is outputting the following:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

I am simply trying to get xcode to show me where I am trying to insert a nil object into an array but it isn't cooperating. Am I doing something wrong here?

I can't post an image of the error since I do not have 10 reputation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode doesn't show the line that causes a crash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703052/xcode-doesnt-show-the-line-that-causes-a-crash)

Comment: pretty obvious. Tells you the error .. Where ever you are adding an object to an array. That object is nil. This is causing the raised exception.

Comment: You need to add an [exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html)

Comment: @grasGendarme I did do that, but I want Xcode to actually highlight the line of code where the exception is being thrown, not just stay inside of main.m and tell me that the thread threw an exception. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: On my machine, when the exception breakpoint is hit, Xcode switch to the line causing the exception. Is it set to "on throw" ?

Comment: See http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1