# UICollectionView layout crashes on iPad, but works fine on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uicollectionview

UICollection view layout crasing in ipad, but works fine iphone.
Will we have to manage  UICollection view layout for ipad differently than iphone?

My code :

```
-(void)reloadData {


    if(collectionData!= nil)
    {
        collectionData = nil;
    }

    [self.collectionView reloadData];

}

-(void)setCollectionView {

    if(self.collectionView == nil) {
            //        self.collectionView = (UICollectionView *)[self.view viewWithTag:_wallCollectionView_tag];
       self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
        self.collectionView.delegate = self;
        self.collectionView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }

}

`enter code here`- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{printf("\n = %s",__FUNCTION__);

    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [collectionData count];
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.width > 320) {
        return CGSizeMake(118, 118);
    }
    return CGSizeMake(100, 100);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a crash log?

Comment: 2015-05-06 18:21:53.777 FlrtAlertVariation[39992:1010801] negative or zero sizes are not supported in the flow layout

 collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:]

and 
[_UIFlowLayoutItem setItemFrame:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fcc35296310
and 

2015-05-06 16:14:56.036 FlrtAlertVariation[37736:957131] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: @RavinderKumar Update your question, don't post the exception in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:     '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]' ***
```

This clearly says, that you trying to access element, which is beyond array bounds. Check next:

1. You use same array for -numberOfItemsInSection method and for -cellForItemAtIndexPath method.
2. You don't mutating array (deleting\adding elements) while collectionView is updating.
3. You accessing datasource array correctly: to retrieve last element of array, which have 5 elements, you should use key "4" - collectionData[4] or collectionData[[collectionData count] - 1].

Comment: Thanks for replied. Let me check out once again my code,  I will give update.

Comment: Hi all, I checked out my code, I did not find any issue in it. But I have a big doubt, this app works fine in iphone, I use Autoresizing it .xib, So that, this app can run in both iphone and ipad devices. Is it any issue ( related to  app crash ) with Autoresizing in .xib file ????

Comment: Your crash log is not complete. Please, post full stacktrace for crash, maybe it make issue more clear.

Comment: 1) [VCWallView2015-05-06 18:21:53.776 myproject[39992:1010801] negative or zero sizes are not supported in the flow layout

Comment: 2)[_UIFlowLayoutItem setItemFrame:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fcc35296310

Comment: 3) 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: 4) [_UIFlowLayoutItem setItemFrame:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7e7ca1d0

(lldb

Comment: 5 ) myproject[31015:651914] *** -[UIViewAnimationState release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fb78bb6eb50
(lldb)

Comment: These are come Randomly in ipad , but does not come in iphone .

Is it any issue ( related to app crash ) with Autoresizing in .xib file ????

Comment: You have strange way of posting stacktrace. I can't tell you anything more. One last thing - add exceptional breakpoint (Left navigator - Breakpoints tab- "+" in bottom left corner - Add exceptional breakpoint), it will stop the program exactly at crash point and you may receive additional info.

Comment: Thanks @ 4esterUA, But  I already did it, It does not  stop the program exactly at crash point. I read reason why it does not stop the program exactly at crash point , The reason is  : If the exception is occurring within those frameworks then you are going to have a hard time since the code is compiled and Xcode can't actually show you the line that caused the exception. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703052/xcode-doesnt-show-the-line-that-causes-a-crash) Thank you

Comment: No problem @  4esterUA, Thank you.