# Application crashes after parsing when scrolling uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

please view my code. Application is working ok but when i scroll fast of up or down it just crashes.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for
>   empty array'

Here is cellforrawatindexpath method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.messageList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ChatListItem"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *nib;
            if ([[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] xml_userType] isEqualToString:@"2"])// THIS IS THE LINE WHERE IT CRASHES
 {
                nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OutGoing" owner:self options:nil];
                textLabel =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(58,12,241,30 )];

                cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

            }else {
                nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InComing" owner:self options:nil];
                textLabel =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(21,12,241,30)];
                cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
            }
            cell = (UITableViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        textLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        userLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
        avatar = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
        timeLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:4];

        NSString * test=[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xml_msg];
        textLabel.text = test;
        textLabel.numberOfLines = 0; 
        [textLabel sizeToFit];
        [cell addSubview:textLabel];
        userLabel.text = [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xml_username];

        avatar.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0;
        avatar.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"patient_name"] isEqualToString:[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xml_username]] || [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"therapist"] isEqualToString:[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xml_username]]) {
            avatar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"p.jpg"];
        }else {
            avatar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"t.jpg"];
        }
        rectTime = (CGRect){0, textLabel.frame.size.height+5, 241, 11};
        timeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rectTime];
        timeLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont smallSystemFontSize]];
        timeLabel.text = [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xml_addedTime];
        timeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        timeLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        [textLabel addSubview:timeLabel];

        return cell;
    }
```

actually i am loading data from xml file which is calling after every 5 sec. i will post my parsing code here.

```
- (void) Parse{
        previusCount = rssOutputData.count;
        rssOutputData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"https://messages_%@.xml",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"xmls_id"]];
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,0),^{

            NSData *xmlData=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:post]];
            xmlParserObject =[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:xmlData];
            [xmlParserObject setDelegate:self];
            [xmlParserObject parse];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [messageList reloadData];
            });
        });
}
```

and here is the NSTIMER from ViewDidLoad

```
 timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target: self selector: @selector(Parse) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
```

here is rest of the parsing code

```
#pragma mark NSXMLParser delegate
//below delegate method is sent by a parser object to provide its delegate when it encounters a start tag
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"message"]){
        xmlStringFileObject =[[XMLChatFile alloc]init];
    } else {
        nodecontent = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    [nodecontent appendString:[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"message"]){
        [rssOutputData addObject:xmlStringFileObject];
        xmlStringFileObject = nil;
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"added"]){
        xmlStringFileObject.xml_addedTime= nodecontent;
        nodecontent = nil;
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"user"]){
        xmlStringFileObject.xml_username= nodecontent;
        nodecontent = nil;
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"text"]){
        xmlStringFileObject.xml_msg= nodecontent;
        nodecontent = nil;
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"user_type"]){
        xmlStringFileObject.xml_userType= nodecontent;
        nodecontent = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the crash message?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: Its because you are setting a `nil` value to `UILabel` or any other control. Check for nil object and set as empty string.

Comment: i did that but still same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, to state the obvious, you're attempting to access an element in one of your arrays which doesn't exist.

Question: if you "enable zombies" in Xcode then re-run your code, does it show you which line is causing the problem ?

[Enable zombies in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36975411/391605)

From there, you should be able to track down the cause.

You could also try sticking something like this at the top of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function...

```
if (rssOutputData == nil)
    return;
if (rssOutputData.count <= objectAtIndex:indexPath.row)
    return;
```

... but I still reckon that this problem is being caused by your `UITableView` attempting to (quickly) load and display data, which your 5-second function is busy emptying-then-refreshing.

After all, that *every-5-seconds* function is emptying your array, then *waiting* to repopulate it using a web service.

Until that web service *completes*, your `UITableView` is bound to a data source which has no data in it...   this can't be healthy !!

```
    rssOutputData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"https://messages_%@.xml",
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"xmls_id"]];
   ... load data from this web service...
```

No wonder it crashes when you're scrolling....

Btw, in your `Parse` function, where do you set the `rssOutputData` value to whatever you've just loaded in from your web service...?

Comment: i disabled the Timer code and after that app isnt crashing anymore but if i did that how am i going to refresh xml and messages if it is updated on server!

Comment: See my final sentence:  Right now, your Parse function "empties" the array you're binding to... but you don't seem to ever fill it again...?  Basically, I don't see where "rssOutputData" is getting set....

Comment: i updated my question with rest of the code. Please view

Comment: I've viewed !   But, my comment remains the same.  You have a UITableView showing, say 100 records.  Your Parse function empties this array  (during which time you can continue scrolling the tableview and it'll crash, as these items no longer exist)  and the UITableView's datasource doesn't get any data again until that web service completes.  To see what I mean, add [messageList reloadData] immediately after the Parse line where you empty your "rssOutputData" array.  Then you'll see the REAL amount of data which your table is able to view at any moment in time....

Comment: yes exactly you are right that is what actually happening most of the times or should i say every time crashes when i scroll. so what can i do to prevent it?? how can i update entries if i dont use timer!! Thanks for you time.

Comment: You basically need to use a NSManagedObjects as your data source.  It's ugly, but it does all the heavy lifting for you.  And if you bind your table to a CoreData database, then go and download mogenerator.  It'll save your sanity.  Just.

Comment: Or, rather than refreshing every 5 seconds, add a "scroll to refresh" control.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110912/discussion-between-mike-gledhill-and-vix-hunk).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your rssOutputData is empty or is lower than the numberOfRows.

See you use rssOutputData and after that you reset it:

```
// ...
previusCount = rssOutputData.count;
rssOutputData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 
// ...
```

and in the code you shared you don't set any values to it again.

Comment: can you please tell me how can set values to it! will appreciate thanks

Comment: yes actually i am saving its previous count to compare if there is any increment in the count. after saving that rssOutputData.count resetting it to get new values from xml.

Comment: is this [xmlParserObject parse]; returning anything? So looking your code, you have to set to rssOutputData an array of XML objects. If [xmlParserObject parse] has been returning an array of XML objects, you can do: rssOutputData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[xmlParserObject parse]];

Comment: So where are you resetting rssOutputData? Could you share the code?